# Is there anyway to calculate mean of beta distribution with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math

This is my code for calculate the mean:

```
syms a b x

f=1/(beta(a,b))*x^(a-1)*(1-x)^(b-1);

int(x*f,x,0,1)

Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 

ans =


int((x*x^(a - 1)*(1 - x)^(b - 1))/beta(a, b), x == 0..1)
```

How can I fix this?

This is my result for TryHArd's:

`syms` `x` `a` `b`

```
f=int(x^(a-1)*(1-x)^(b-1),x,0,1)
```

Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.

```
f =

piecewise([0 < real(a) and 0 < real(b), beta(a, b)], [real(a) <= 0 or real(b) <= 0, int(x^(a - 1)*(1 - x)^(b - 1), x == 0..1)])
```

My result did not show the same `gamma(a)*gamma(b)/gamma(a+b)` as TryHard did.

Comment: Your entire problem boils down to the fact that you're using a numeric  function (`beta`) inside of a symbolic expression instead of representing it directly as symbolic (though maybe you just want the numeric result anyways, in which case you should be using any symbolic stuff). The `beta` function is calculated numerically in a special way to be efficient and accurate. If you look at the help for `beta` (or Wikipedia) you'll see the formula you should use. Thus, @TryHard's solution is the actual correct one given your question.

Comment: I am sorry TryHard. Actually, just as horchler said, I did not know what to do with this post because I found no answers. Mathematica is new to me and if I want to use it, I have to learn it which will take more time. As for TryHard's post, I tried his code but I did not work for me (at least for my version R12).

Comment: Really... Please forgive my stupidity... I have an experience that I should not ask too much because people will be annoyed by it, and that experience follows me all the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by `beta` you mean

> beta(z,w) = integral from 0 to 1 of t.^(z-1) .* (1-t).^(w-1) dt.

Then break down the problem:

```
>> int((x^(a-1))*((1-x)^(b-1)),x,0,1)

ans =

gamma(b)*gamma(a)/gamma(a+b)
```

The desired integral is equivalent to:

```
>> bint=int((x^(a-1))*((1-x)^(b-1)),x,0,1);
>> int( x*((x^(a-1))*((1-x)^(b-1)))/bint,x,0,1)

ans =

a/(a+b)
```

(This was computed with an earlier version of the Matlab SMT (on R14), but should serve as a guide.)

Comment: Yes, it seeems so. I have tried to input your code, but the answers is just the same: Integral expressions cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

The mean of the Beta distritution is `1/(1+b/a)`. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram alpha is capable of it.

Computing the definite integral directly exceeds maximum standard computation time, but it can find the [indefinite integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%28x%28x%5E%28alpha-1%29%281-x%29%5E%28delta-1%29%29%2Fbeta%28alpha%2Cdelta%29%2C+x%29). Limiting that expression to `x` between 0 and 1, means simply equating `x` to `1`. This results in [this expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%CE%93%28%CE%B1%2B%CE%B4%29+2F1%281%2B%CE%B1%2C+1-%CE%B4%2C+2%2B%CE%B1%2C+1%29%29%2F%28%281%2B%CE%B1%29+%CE%93%28%CE%B1%29+%CE%93%28%CE%B4%29%29), the alternate form of which is the standard form of the mean of the beta distribution.

Wolfram Mathematica (& Alpha) is simply better at symbolic math than MuPad. I'd advise to use MATLAB only for what it rocks at: *numerical* math. Other than perhaps some fringe cases, I do not expect MuPad to ever come close to what has been achieved by Wolfram.

Comment: Wow, so that is why my mentor said that Mathematica is the most famous software of all. MATLAB is only for economists. Thanks for the tip man !!!

Comment: @SONTO: wait, I didn't say that...I work with MATLAB all the time, and I'm  a space engineer...

Comment: @SONTO: Purely analytical methods are able to cover perhaps 5% of all real-world engineering problems. Numerical methods will get you to around 90%. So not *only*, but *mostly*.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis and the other 5%? (we make up the answer ;>))

Comment: @TryHard: That 90% *includes* that 5% (or a bit less, but oh well). The "missing" 10% constitute the (current) unsolved problems. In any case, the point was that the amount of real-world problems you can tackle with numerical math is stupendously greater than what you can do with analysis alone. Try solving `M = E-e*sin(E)` for `E`, with `0 < e < 1` and `-pi < M < +pi` both known (Kepler's equation).

Comment: How does this answer the question? And why is it accepted? The problem is that the OP used `beta` in a symbolic expression.

Comment: @horchler: so, post an answer!

Comment: @horchler: mine too...¯\\(°_°)/¯

Comment: I think the OP was somewhat confused about what to do... if he feels comfortable with mathematica good for him. Thanks @horchler.

Comment: @TryHard: never hurts to replace that blunt rusty old handsaw with a shiny new electric precision saw :) Just never throw away that rusty old saw, it might come in handy when you don't have an extension cord long enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the result for some specific parameters alpha and beta, you can use `betastat`. This function can be used also with vectors, like that:

```
A=[4 4 4];
B=[5 6 7];
[m,v]=betastat(A,B)
```

This will give you a 3-elements vector for both `m` (mean) and `v` (variance). For this example, `m` will be the means of beta(4,5), beta(4,6) and beta(4,7). (Note that "beta" here denotes the distribution, not the beta-function, like `beta` function on Matlab).

If you need a general (mathematical) solution, see Rody's answer. Wolfram is much appropriate for this.

EDIT: You can define f (in your code) by the function `betapdf` instead of the whole formula you wrote over there.